# node mongoose is it possible to populate subdocuments?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am a lost in trying to populate documents with nested references

First I have Group document, with nested subdocuments  Group > Roles > Permissions
defined with the following model :

**group.model.js**

```
const PermissionSchema = new Schema({
  resourceName: { type: String, trim: true },
  authorizedActions: [ { type: String, trim: true }]},
  { _id: false }
);

const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  permissions: [PermissionSchema]
});

/**
 * Group Schema
 */
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  roles: [RoleSchema]
});
```

Then I have a User document , each User will have multiple Groups/Roles references

**user/model.js**

```
const RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ roleId: { type: ObjectId } }, { _id: false })

const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  groupId: { type: ObjectId }, 
  roles: [RoleSchema] }, { _id: false })

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  groups: [GroupSchema],
});
```

When loading a user, with The User.get(id), I would like to populate the user references with the Groups/Roles documents values.

```
UserSchema.statics = {
  /**
   * Get user
   * @param {ObjectId} id - The objectId of user.
   * @returns {Promise<User, APIError>}
   */
  get(id) {
      return this.findById(id)
      .populate('WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE ?)
      .exec()
      .then((user) => {
        if (user) { return user; }
        const err = new APIError('No such user exists!', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  },
```

1- Should I change my models ?
2- How should I write the populate() path ?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: have you tried this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ ?

Comment: There's a difference between [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) (which is what you're using) and [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Subdocuments are embedded (part of the "parent" document) whilst population works by referring to other models/collections. I assume that you want to use population?

Comment: thanks for your feedback... I guess in this business cas population is recommended:   user.roles should be always up-to-date with latest Group/Roles states.  Currently Roles are suddocuments in Groups... and I bet I should define Groups and Roles separately in order to be able to reference roles from user...